# String to datetime with CET/CEST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, data-conversion

I am having some difficulties converting a string to datetime in PHP.

The string can end with both CEST and CET as timezone, so I guess I have to somehow split before that? I am not looking to store the CET or CEST. I only want the date converted to a datetime.

This is the strings:

`Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CET` and `Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CEST`

But also, the spaces in the strings are `&nbsp;` and not regular spaces. So in HTML it looks like this:

`Dec&nbsp;27&nbsp;2017,&nbsp;22:46:15&nbsp;CET` and `Dec&nbsp;27&nbsp;2017,&nbsp;22:46:15&nbsp;CEST`

I want it converted in to: `2017-12-27 22:46:15` and then insert that to my database. I figured out how to change this in an SQL query (my column is called **lastlogin**) and I do that by doing this:

`STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(lastlogin,char(160),' '),'C',1), '%b %d %Y, %T')`

But I'd really like to do this in PHP. So let's say my variable with the date is called `$lastlogin`, how would I apply that SQL logic to my PHP? the `char(160)` in SQL is the `&nbsp;`, I am not sure about PHP.

Edit:
I am storing it in $character->lastlogin variable. (note: apparently it is getting `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`)

```
$character->lastlogin = str_replace('&#160;', ' ', $character->lastlogin);
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s e', $character->lastlogin);
$character->lastlogin = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Gives me this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
// CET Timezone (+01:00)
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s e', 'Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CET');

// change timezone to UTC (+00:00) (if necessary)
$datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$output = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// output: 2017-12-27 21:46:15
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in`. I don't think it recognizes it as a date with the `&nbsp;` in the string. Also I don't want to change the timezones. It doesn't matter if it is CEST or CET. I just want to grab the date and time before that (even if it has 1 hour difference).

Comment: what is you date string? because you provided incorrect date string, you should ensure it has this format `Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CET`, `Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CEST` etc..

Comment: It is a string in HTML, as I wrote above. It uses `&nbsp;` instead of normal spaces. Right now I tried this: `$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s e', str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $lastlogin));` and `$output = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` but then it says it is a boolean?

Comment: String is: `Dec&nbsp;27&nbsp;2017,&nbsp;22:46:15&nbsp;CET`

Comment: the better way you should replace the string before parsing with `DateTime`, `$str = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str);`

Comment: I don't understand why it thinks it's a boolean all of a sudden... I'll update my code in my post. Please have a look

Comment: In my database, if I change to a VARCHAR and just insert the string, I get this value: `Dec&#160;27&#160;2017,&#160;22:46:15&#160;CET`

Comment: you get this error because you provided incorrect datetime format for `DateTime` parsing

Comment: i found no problem after replacing `&#160;`, it got `Dec 27 2017, 22:46:15 CET` and got the output correctly

Comment: I got it to work when I put it all on same line. Very weird! It just would not work, and kept saying it was a boolean when I didn't have it on same line (WTF????). My line: `DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s e', str_replace('&#160;', ' ', $character->lastlogin))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` Thanks for your help! +1 Rep!!!

Comment: @LeeCheung if you check the docs, it says the return type of `createFromFormat` is `DateTime|false`, meaning either a date object or a boolean false. When you try calling the format method on false, you get the error you're saying. In the end, Ben's code unfortunately did not handle failures properly - always do that and you'll be avoid a whole lot of weird errors.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but not optimal.

Here's what we know:

- the input date string is from html, and might contain special characters encoded as html entities
- html entities are decoded as utf-8

  - but, `createFromFormat` expects plain old ascii*
- we should never underestimate errors/failures
- the date has a specific format

---

*I deduced this after some trial and error, I read this in the docs:

```
 (space)      Zero or more spaces, tabs, NBSP (U+A0), or           Example: "\t", " "
              NNBSP (U+202F) characters
```

..and further noted that in [UTF-8, NBSP is `U+C2 U+A0`, not just `A0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings).

---

```php
$dateWithHtmlEntities = 'Dec&nbsp;27&nbsp;2017,&nbsp;22:46:15&nbsp;CET';
$dateWithUTF8Chars = html_entity_decode($dateWithHtmlEntities);
$dateInPlainASCII = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $dateWithUTF8Chars);
$dateTimeObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s T', $dateInPlainASCII);

if (!$dateTimeObject) {
    // TODO handle errors your own way
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Date could not be parsed: ' . $decodedDate);
}

echo 'Final date: ' . $dateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

PS: `US-ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` means "convert to ascii; translate possible characters (e.g. ü => ue); and ignore the rest that can't be translated".

PPS: using encoding/decoding functions instead of `str_replace` has the advantage of automatically handling any other special characters that you didn't consider. Alternatively, a potentially better approach, (than str_replace), is to use regex (`preg_replace`) with [character classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

PPPS: Can't stress this enough - always handle errors and failures, especially when experimenting with new code.

Et voilà: https://3v4l.org/CLgfO